# How to set the first day of the week in calendars of Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm planning a sprint using Azure DevOps. When I want to set the days of for a developer, the calendar shows Sunday as the 1st day of the week, while I'd have Monday as 1st day. Is there any according setting I can change?

[image: Azure DevOps Sprint Capacity]

Comment: check Project Settings > Team Configuration and click on the General tab. do the "Working Days" checkboxes do what you want?

Comment: @FrankThomas no, they don't. These checkboxes just define the working days, but they don't define which day of the week should be shown as first in the calendar (see image above in my post).

Comment: yeah, you are not going to find an option for that. the calendar control is a basic component. you will have to accept that while the Sunday column appears first, that does not symbolize the beginning of the work-week. Sorry bout that.

Comment: Interpreting this thread https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/weeks-start-on-sunday-not-monday/375276 it seems that it's not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1. I am using the Firefox browser.

The start of the week can't be configured directly per project or per team. It is derived from the locale of the current logged in user.

In order to set monday as start of the week you have to choose a locale which defines it. This is done in the profile settings:

[image: My profile]

[image: Profile settings]

The result looks like this:
[image: Monday as start of week]

Comment: This seems not to work: although my locale is set to "Deutsch (Schweiz)", Sunday is still shown as first day of the week in the calendars. Same if I try to set it to "Deutsch (Deutschland)".

Comment: Maybe this is related to the used browser. I am using Firefox. It may also depend on the used version of azure devops.